# Uncompressed Video explicit formats. RGB24

Tags: video, codec, avi

Is there a readily available documentation or standard for uncompressed video stream? Preferably RGB24. It doesn't matter if it usese RGB or some other color pallete for compression really because there seems to be an abundance of information on the math necessary to convert. What seems to be in short supply is the actual format of the data streams? I'm not sure if it is because it is proprietary or what, but I can not seem to find a standard which would allow me to write a video encoder.

To help make clear what it is that I want. Consider how a single bitmap for an image might be formated in a file. RGBRGBRGBRGB... and so on. What I would have is a single integer representing the image and If I knew how it was encoded I could render it. Now for video we would have an array of these single data streams. And so I could devise some way to encode that. But there wouldn't be a single codec available to interpret my scheme. So I need to know the schema for encoding a video stream into a file.

I am targeting windows. Basically I was able to find good documentation on RIFF's and AVI's a container format. So now I get a 'movi' Chucnk which contains video/audio data chunks. I need a way to encode/decode that. Specifically for uncompressed video. But really any codec that is fully documented would be acceptable.

- I would like to NOT use an existing API which bypasses the underlying data stream format.
- Is DV or Digital Video (old specification used for VHS cassettes and other media) compatible with windows codecs, if so maybe it would work? Or maybe HDMI if HDMI stream can be interpreted by windows codecs?

Answer (score 1):

AVI supports uncompressed RGB video format. You can set FOURCC to 0x00000000. The properties of the video is then decided by AVI header information. You can see some sample raw AVI files at http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/Uncompressed/

EDIT: It is hard to find proper documentation on how to add any codec within AVI container. I would recommend instead to find a file that works and then to examine its content/structure using tools like [RiffPad](http://www.menasoft.com/blog/?p=34) or [AVI-Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/AVI-Viewer/3000-13631_4-75616919.html). Another option is to see how open source tools like VLC create an AVI file with desired codec inside.

Comment: So would I basically view them in hex editor and work out the stream format? It seems like that should work but have never done it before. Do you know if there is something well built for parsing avi's as binaries?

Comment: @marshalcraft I would recommend using RiffPad, an AVI file viewer. More details are at http://www.menasoft.com/blog/?p=34

Comment: thanks. But I have managed to at least find 'movi00db line in hex editor. My understanding is that it is the movie list, and the first stream is a video stream. Now I have no idea what to make of what comes next. It is 16 bpp which i guess has this format, rrrrr gggggg bbbbb?

Comment: So the encoding should be every 0xFFFF represents a pixel? I tried working out the normal 24rgb for it and I get color of 132 red, 8 green, and 140 blue. This is a brighter purple color which doens't really seem to appear in the 16bpp movie. Though with out being able to isolate the pixels closely to see i can't tell.

Comment: I feel that I am close, I have made it all the way to the 'movi' and video stream data but now i dont know what to make of it? Please respond...